# Найти неизвестную точку треугольника на координатной плоскости

Tags: математика, геометрия, тригонометрия

[image: Треугольник ABC на оси координат X, Y]

*Рис. 1. Равнобедренный треугольник ABC на координатной плоскости x, y*

---

Ребят нужна помощь с решением задачи. В геометрии не силен, поэтому формулы с интернета никак не помогли. 
Кто сможет написать вменяемую формулу для нахождения точки B?

### В общем суть нашей задачи:

У нас есть Равнобедренный *треугольник ABC* на плоскости **X**, **Y**.
Нам известны координаты точек **A (x1, y1)** и точки **C (x2, y2)**, а так же их углы. Так же мы знаем угол точки **B (x3, y3)**. Важно понимать, что треугольник на плоскости координат не всегда стоит ровно, у точек **A** и **C** - **y** не одинаков.

Нужно найти точку **B (x3, y3)**

Comment: Перестаньте называть координатную *плоскость* XY осью.

Comment: @Igor извините, я просто в этом не особо компетентен

Comment: @Igor и кстати в названии темы, это не я изменил название на оси координат

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
M = (A + C) / 2
D = (C - A) / 2
B.x = M.x - D.y * tan(A)
B.y = M.y + D.x * tan(A)
```

Comment: Только таких точек в общем случае 2.

Comment: @Harry  Да, я привёл знаки для указанной на рисунке ориентации

Comment: @MBo правильно понимаю, что складывать вектора нужно примерно так:

(A + C) / 2; ~
Mx = (Ax + Cx) / 2; My = (Ay + Cy) / 2

ну и отнимать собственно так же?

Comment: @reAL   Да, верно

Comment: @MBo спасибо. Ты мне помог с данной проблемой. Это я использовал для решения задачи с "правильными" уголками https://prnt.sc/r7ga7q в своей программе